# How to let public access to the sitemap page?

Tags: 7, users

I am using the [Site map](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) module that creates a page called sitemap. However, I cannot access it if I am not logged in, as the access is denied for that page for the anonymous users.

How can I let public access to the sitemap page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is permission based, so you need to give anonymous users the `access site map` permission.

From the module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function site_map_permission() {
  return array(
    'access site map' => array(
      'title' => t('View published site map'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function site_map_menu() {
  $items['admin/config/search/sitemap'] = array(
    'title' => 'Site map',
    'description' => 'Control what should be displayed on the site map.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('site_map_admin_settings_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    'file' => 'site_map.admin.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['sitemap'] = array(
    'title' => 'Site map',
    'description' => 'Display a site map with RSS feeds.',
    'page callback' => 'site_map_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access site map'),
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Actually no. In `admin/people/permissions` I have only             `Administer XML sitemap settings`.

Comment: @EK Kosmos, then you need to update your site map version

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have not seen the permission in `admin/people/permissions`. Now is ok. Thanks.

Comment: @Ek Kosmos That is the permission used by XML sitemap, which is a different module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno True.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Module >> Sitemap >> Permission" (on OPERATIONS tab). Look for the Site map module, and select the suitable checkboxes.